# How do I make a Material for Lips?

Tags: texturing, materials

I am making a character and I know that I have to use something to make the lips have a textured material but I am not sure exactly what a lip texture needs or how to make it. I am doing male lips and have looked online but haven't found anything. Does anyone know what I should do to make the lips look like lips?

Comment: hello, I think your question is a bit too vague, what have you done so far?

Comment: Well, I sculpted the lips and I am trying to figure out what kind of material I would use for it. I want to make somewhat realistic lips so I am wondering what kind of material that would need? How do I make the lips look like lips? I was thinking I could do something in the shading tab but I am confused on what to do to make lips.